# C++ multiple files with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file

I am brand new to C++. I have a question on how to run a C++ program that contains multiple files. I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express as the IDE. I don't know why, but the program won't run. I am pretty sure that my coding is all right. How can I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code in the two files (the project name is PracticeConsoleMultipleFiles and I created the project as a Win32 Console Application):

NewFile1.cpp:

```
int add(int x, int y){
return x + y;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int add(int x, int y);

int main(){
using namespace std;
cout << "The sum of 9 and 9 is " << add(9, 9) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

When I build my program, I get this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PracticeConsoleMultipleFiles, Configuration: Debug
 Win32 ------
1>  NewFile1.cpp
1>c:\users\timothylee\documents\visual studio 2010    \projects\main\practiceconsolemultiplefiles\newfile1.cpp(4): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?
1>  Main.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

and when I run it, it says that:

```
This project is out of date: PracticeConsoleMultipleFiles - Debug Win32
```

Comment: The error exactly says what the problem is. Did you even **tried** to fix it by yourself?

Comment: "Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?" The first line of every cpp file must be #include "StdAfx.h" That's not part of C++ but it is part of Visual C++.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP: That's not a requirement at all; it just happens to be the Visual Studio default setting for precompiled headers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you, as a beginner to c++,  start off with a blank project when using visual studio, this will not place the code including stdafx.h in your main.cpp which should solve the error you are getting